# Deployed asp.net core mvc app not browsable in azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core MVC application using Identity Server 4 which runs fine locally. However, when I deploy it to an Azure app service (the deploy is performed automatically based on check-in so no manual steps) the app fails to work as expected

I can:

- Access static files out of the www root directory
- Access .well-known/openid-configuration and see the JSON returned

I cannot:

- Browse to the homepage and get the Identity server welcome page
- View any MVC “pages” (e..g /account/login)

My configure method isn’t particularly complex:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
                AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
                AutomaticChallenge = false
            });



            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

But nothing on the MVC side seems to be functioning. When I browse to the homepage I simply get the View cannot be found:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `publishOptions` section in `project.json`file - you have section with subsection `include`. You need to add a relative path to "Views" folder here.

```
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      ...
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Wow. I did not even know that section existed. How/Why would it get created without the Views folder? I've added in wwwroot/Views/areas/appsettings/web.config now and its working. Thanks :)