# .Net Core MVC Deployment (Publish) missing views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnet-development-server

I am trying to publish my MVC application in .NET core. I tried the File system, but it's missing all the View related files and throws error as soon as accessed.

After copying the view folder it started working . I am not sure If it's missing other web components also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deployed asp.net core mvc app not browsable in azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717145/deployed-asp-net-core-mvc-app-not-browsable-in-azure)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have `Views` in your `PublishOptions` of Project.json.

If you are maintaing views inside Areas then make sure you have added `Areas/**/Views`

Sample below-

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
    ]
  },
```

See if this helps.

Comment: What would it look like for a classical Asp.Net application? Is there something similar in the .csproj?

Answer (score 3):

edit your.csproj file and add PreserveCompilationContext as true and MvcRazorCompileOnPublish as false

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

then views will be included in publish

Answer (score 0):

Areas do not work this way... So adding

> Areas/**/Views

It might not work for you, It has not for me.

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
    ]
  },
```

If you replace it with this, It will definitely work..

```
 "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views/**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project and add

```
<pre>
MvcRazorCompileOnPublish=false 
</pre>
```

in xml file property group

this will force publishing the view files as .cshtml file as usual.

Note : precompiled views within dll is faster at runtime

Answer (score 0):

With .Net Core MVC when publishing the View folder is not suppose to go instead you should have a file yourprojectname.Views.dll, check if you have this dll.

Depending where u publishing to you have to target that OS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog.

Also you should show the error you getting, could be related to many other things such as permission.